# How to get human-readable type of a complex expression at compilation time?

Tags: c++, gcc, types

Suppose there's a complex expression `EXPRESSION`, and it's quite hard even for the IDE to find some of the methods called in it etc., so it's very hard to figure out the type it evaluates to. Currently to make the compiler (gcc) print the human-readable type I'm using a construct like

```
struct {} s=EXPRESSION;
```

which won't compile for any expression if it evaluates not to `{}`. In this case gcc says something like

> Conversion from Type_I_am_Interested_In to non-scalar type main()::<anonymous struct> requested

, which allows me to see the `Type_I_am_Interested_In`.

My question is now, is there a nicer way to get human-readable `Type_I_am_Interested_In` using some gcc/clang extensions or whatever instead of relying on error message format?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) to get the type of the expression and then use partially specialized templates and [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) (demangle via [cxxabi.h](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.4/a00695.html)) to create a readable form as you like.

While you can skip the template decomposition step, you will receive slightly less information without it.